# ggplot2. Использование geom_ribbon в цикле

Tags: r, ggplot2

Захотел я сделать красивый график с затухающей тенью в ggplot2.

Вот такой код работает замечательно:

```
# библиотека
library(ggplot2)
# Создадим данные
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

m <- 1500 #Обратная ширина полосы

#Базовый график
h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))+geom_line(aes(x=year, y=level), color='blue')+theme_bw()

# График с 10 полосами тени
h + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*1,  ymax=level), alpha=0.1, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*2,  ymax=level-(level/m)*1), alpha=0.09, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*3,  ymax=level-(level/m)*2), alpha=0.08, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*4,  ymax=level-(level/m)*3), alpha=0.07, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*5,  ymax=level-(level/m)*4), alpha=0.06, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*6,  ymax=level-(level/m)*5), alpha=0.05, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*7,  ymax=level-(level/m)*6), alpha=0.04, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*8,  ymax=level-(level/m)*7), alpha=0.03, fill='blue')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*9,  ymax=level-(level/m)*8), alpha=0.02, fill='blue')+    
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*10, ymax=level-(level/m)*9), alpha=0.01, fill='blue')
```

Ага, подумал я. Сделаю функцию и буду везде рисовать красивые графики.
Но не тут-то было. Когда в цикле пытаешься добавлять к графику этот самый geom_ribbon - выходит что-то не то. 
Вот, пробовал пока просто цикл, не оформляя в процедуру:

```
count <- 5 # количество разбиений
start_alpha <- 0.1  # начальная прозрачность
p <- h
for (i in 0:(count-1))
{
  p <- p + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*i,  ymax=level-(level/m)*(i+1)), alpha=start_alpha-(start_alpha/count)*i, fill='blue')
}

print(p)
```

Долго думал, смотрел лист (p) который генерится в цикле.
Складывается впечатление, что все слои на самом деле создаются, но вот переменная i как это сказать, не используется по значению, а остается ссылкой, на каждой итерации цикла.

Вот пример, из которого это видно:

```
i <- 0 
print(p)

i <- 1
print(p)
```

Как нибудь победить эту проблему можно ?

**UPD.** Пробовал aes_string. Не помогло. Пробовал вот так:

```
geom_ribbon(aes_string(ymin="level-(level/m)*i",  ymax="level-(level/m)*(i+1)"), alpha=0.05, fill='blue')
```

Comment: `aes_string` попробуйте.

Comment: Не помогло. Результат такой-же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как подсказали в комментариях, нужно использовать  `aes_string()`. Однако, в цикле переменная `level` не видна, поэтому нужно обратиться напрямую.

```
p <- ggplot(huron, aes(year)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = level), color = 'blue') +
    theme_bw()
for (i in 0:(count - 1)) {
    p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes_string(
        ymin = p$data$level - (p$data$level / m) * i,
        ymax=p$data$level - (p$data$level / m) * (i + 1)),
        alpha = start_alpha - (start_alpha / count) * i,
        fill = 'blue')
}
print(p)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Основная идея для Вашего случая - сформировать текстовую строку с фрагментом необходимого кода, который в последующем выполнить. Ниже приведен работающий код на основе Вашего примера:

```
# Функция создает строковую переменную, которая в дальнейшем исполняется
# max.count - количество разбиений
# width - обратная ширина полосы
# start.transparence - начальная прозрачность

Creater.Command.String <- function (max.count, width, start.transparence){
  rslt.strng = ""
  #создаем строку 
  for (i in 1:max.count){
    # rslt.strng <- paste(rslt.strng, "+", i)
    rslt.strng = paste(rslt.strng, "+", "geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=level-(level/m)*", i, ",  ymax=level), alpha=", start.transparence*i, ", fill='blue')")
  }
  return (rslt.strng)
}

# библиотека
library(ggplot2)
# Создадим данные
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

m <- 1500 #Обратная ширина полосы

#Базовый график
h <- ggplot(huron, aes(year))+geom_line(aes(x=year, y=level), color='blue')+theme_bw()

# формируем строку для выполнения
run.string <- Creater.Command.String(15, m, 0.01)

# дополняем переменной, содержащей Базовый график
run.string <- paste("h", run.string)
# print (run.string)   # смотрим получившийся результат

# выполняем код в переменной run.string
eval(parse(text = run.string))
```

Дальнейшее улучшение кода функции: добавить Базовый график, выполнение непосредственно в функции